# How does the following quicksort method works?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, quicksort, partitioning

I wrote my own Quicksort method for educational purposes. In order to improve it, I took a look at .NET source code to see how to LINQ `OrderBy()` method is implemented.

I found the following [Quicksort method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,28b56d00f5cd66de) :

```
void QuickSort(int[] map, int left, int right) {
    do {
        int i = left;
        int j = right;
        int x = map[i + ((j - i) >> 1)];
        do {
            while (i < map.Length && CompareKeys(x, map[i]) > 0) i++;
            while (j >= 0 && CompareKeys(x, map[j]) < 0) j--;
            if (i > j) break;
            if (i < j) {
                int temp = map[i];
                map[i] = map[j];
                map[j] = temp;
            }
            i++;
            j--;
        } while (i <= j);
        if (j - left <= right - i) {
            if (left < j) QuickSort(map, left, j);
            left = i;
        }
        else {
            if (i < right) QuickSort(map, i, right);
            right = j;
        }
    } while (left < right);
}
```

I am trying to understand the inner workings.
AFAIK it looks very similar to [Hoare partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme) but with some slight optimisations.

What is unclear to me is :

- Why do we recurse only one side of the pivot after partitionning ? (depending the result of the `if (j - left <= right - i)` )
- Why do we have a `do { ... } while (left < right)` over the whole thing ? Is it because we recurse only one side of the pivot as suggested above ?
- Why is there a `if (i < j)` conditional test before the swap ? Isn't the `break;` statement before enough?

In comparison, here is how my actual implementation Quicksort looks (straight implementation of Hoare partition scheme)

```
void QuickSort(int[] map, int left, int right)
{
    if (left < right)
    {
        int i = left - 1;
        int j = right + 1;
        int x = map[left + ((right - left) >> 1)];

        while (true)
        {
            do { i++; } while (Compare(map[i], x) < 0);
            do { j--; } while (Compare(map[j], x) > 0);

            if (i >= j) break;

            int temp = map[i];
            map[i] = map[j];
            map[j] = temp;
        }

        QuickSort(map, left, j);
        QuickSort(map, j + 1, right);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the CompareKeys method do? I'm having trouble understanding it

Comment: It compares two elements according the keys that have been defined using `OrderBy()` and `ThenBy()` methods (with keyselector lamdbas). Those keys are computed once before sorting (to avoid computing them each time you need to compare two items). `map[]` is an array containing indices to those keys. When you do the sorting, you swap those indexes, not the actual objects to be sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why do we recurse only one side of the pivot after partitionning ?
>   (depending the result of the if (j - left <= right - i) )

To minimize recursion depth (and stack usage). When we treat larger partition as soon as possible and do recursion only for smaller partition, depth does not rise above log(n)

> Why do we have a do { ... } while (left < right) over the whole thing ?

Items before `left` and after `right` are sorted, so these indexes meet when all array is sorted

> Why is there a if (i < j) conditional test before the swap ?

Just to avoid unnecessary swap for equal indexes

Comment: For first part : this is indeed what is done : as stated in this [comment](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,2398) of `DepthLimitedQuickSort()` method for `Array.Sort()`

Comment: No, link describes another sorting approach - switching to another sorting method (introsort uses both quicksort and heapsort code pieces). 1st part is mentioned in wiki page about quicksort and described in some algorithmic courses like Sedgewick book.